# Route attribute Name property

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, routes, asp.net-web-api2

I have ProductsController and OwnersController:

```
public class ProductsController : ApiController
{

    //constructor is here

    // GET /api/products
    public IHttpActionResult GetProducts()
    {
        return Ok(new ApiResponse());
    }

    // GET /api/products/{productCode}
    [HttpGet, Route("api/products/{productCode}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetProductByCode(string productCode)
    {
         return Ok(new ApiResponse());
    }

    // POST /api/products
    public IHttpActionResult PostProduct(Product product /*my class*/)
    {
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = product.Id }, product);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly.
But now I create second controller and do the same things but **I get the error when trying POST method. Another methods work well!**

Lets take a look at the code first:

```
public class OwnersController : ApiController
{
    // constructor

    // GET /api/owners/{label}
    // GET /api/owners/{label}?skip=1&take=4
    [Route("api/owners/{label}")]
    public IHttpActionResult GetOwnersExamples(string label, int skip=0, int take=10)
    {
        return Ok(new ApiResponse());
    }
    // POST /api/owners/{productCode}
    //[HttpPost]
    [Route("api/owners/{productCode}"/*, Name = "CreateOwner"*/)]
    public IHttpActionResult PostOwner(string productCode, Owner owner)
    {
        return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Owner.Id }, owner);
    }  
}
```

Error message:

> UrlHelper.Link must not return null

---

My **RouteConfig**:

```
config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
    name: "DefaultApi",
    routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
    defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
);
```

As I understand problem that `CreateAtRoute` method must get another `RouteName`. As you see I can solve the problem by adding Route Name parameter (commented now) and replace `"DefaultApi"` with `"CreateOwner"` but it looks like a hack. I believe there is another method to do it avoiding `Name Property`.

P.S. Looks like my Web API can see only first controller (ProductsController) - any other methods doesn't work if I delete explicit Route `[Route("...")]`...

Comment: What line does the error occur on? Could you provide a stack trace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve the problem using next steps:

1. Delete all `[RoutePrefix]` for controller - let them work by default - it works perfectly for simple requests.
2. **IMPORTANT:** check all methods for duplicates! Problem was I had 2 methods with routes `api/controller/{label}` and `api/controller/{parameter}` - it can't understand which of them to use by default. (Or use explicit uri: `api/controller?label=1`)
3. **IMPORTANT:** avoid to put into api methods a lot of complex types - create Wrapper for them and put only one parameter!

All this actions let me delete excess attributes and make methods more readable.

Here is the result:

```
public IHttpActionResult PostOwner(OwnerWrapper modelWrapper)
{
    string productCode = modelWrapper.Product.Code;
    Owner owner = modelWrapper.Owners[0];

    return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = Owner.Id }, owner);
}
```

It is just test case, so we can see `productCode` is never used, but my real realization is more difficult.

Answer (score 3):

> As I understand problem that CreateAtRoute method must get another
>   RouteName. As you see I can solve the problem by adding Route Name
>   parameter (commented now) and replace "DefaultApi" with "CreateOwner"
>   but it looks like a hack. I believe there is another method to do it
>   avoiding Name Property.

Your understanding is almost correct. However you should specify a name not for the current route, but for the one that points to created resource. `CreatedAtRoute` fills response [Location](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location) header that should contain a GET-able URI for newly created resource.

Here is a working sample:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("api/owners/{id}", Name = "GetOwnerById")]
public IHttpActionResult GetOwner(int id)
{
    //  Obtain the owner by id here
    return Ok(new ApiResponse());
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("api/owners/{productCode}"/*, Name = "CreateOwner"*/)]
public IHttpActionResult PostOwner(string productCode, Owner owner)
{
    return CreatedAtRoute("GetOwnerById", new { id = owner.Id }, owner);
}
```

(Note: For get this example working, you should comment `GetOwnersExamples` action, otherwise multiple action will match your GET request.)

You said that it looks like a hack, but it is not. `CreatedAtRoute` takes a route name as argument and you should provide it. How otherwise the proper action will be selected and `Location` header will be built?

Comment: Thank you for contribution! Reading your answer I found the solution. Still the answer is another, you could not give it to me because of lack of information :)